# How to deploy kyber network proxy locally and test with truffle?

Tags: solidity, truffle, proxy-contracts

I am trying to deploy a proxy from Kyber Network for local development. So far I have pulled down the workshop repo and I have successfully deployed all the contracts successfully. I have the following contract:

```js
import "./Investor.sol";
import "./IKyberNetworkProxy.sol";

contract Trader is Investor {

    uint256 public platformFeeBps;

    constructor(
        IKyberNetworkProxy _kyberProxy,
        uint256  _platformFeeBps
    ) public
    {
        kyberProxy = _kyberProxy;
        platformFeeBps = _platformFeeBps;
    }

    function getConversionRates(
        IERC20 srcToken,
        IERC20 destToken,
        uint256 srcQty
    ) public
      view
      returns (uint256)
    {
      return kyberProxy.getExpectedRateAfterFee(srcToken, destToken, srcQty, platformFeeBps, '');
    }

}
```

And it is being deployed in this migration:

```js
const Trader = artifacts.require("Trader");
const NetworkProxy = artifacts.require('IKyberNetworkProxy');
const PLATFORM_FEE = 25;
module.exports = async function(deployer, network)  {

  const kyberNetWorkProxyAddress = network == 'ropsten' ? '0x818E6FECD516Ecc3849DAf6845e3EC868087B755' : '0xf7b8C85953aF2524CcEC98066FCebAF8db27De02';

  const proxy = await NetworkProxy.at(kyberNetWorkProxyAddress);
  deployer.deploy(Trader, proxy, PLATFORM_FEE);
};
```

Running
`truffle migrate --network development`
will execute successfully but the trouble seems to be when I am running `truffle test tests/Trader.js`

This is my Trader test file:

```js
/* libraries used */

const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');
const vals = require('./lib/testValuesCommon.js');

/* Contracts in this test */

const Trader = artifacts.require("../contracts/Trader.sol");
const KyberProxy = artifacts.require("../contracts/IkyberNetworkProxy.sol");

/* Useful aliases */

const toBN = web3.utils.toBN;

contract("Trader", (accounts) => {
  const TRADER_ID = 1;

  const OVERFLOW_NUMBER = toBN(2, 10).pow(toBN(256, 10)).sub(toBN(1, 10));

  const TraderStatus = {OPEN: 0,  PAUSED: 1, CLOSED: 2};
  
  const oneEth = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether');

  const ETH_ADDRESS = '0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee';
  const KNC_ADDRESS = '0xdd974d5c2e2928dea5f71b9825b8b646686bd200';
  const WBTC_ADDRESS = '0xdd974d5c2e2928dea5f71b9825b8b646686bd200';

  const PLATFORM_FEE = 25;

  const owner = accounts[0];
  const trader = accounts[1];
  const investorA = accounts[2];
  const investorB = accounts[3];

  let instance;
  let proxy;

  before(async () => {
    proxy = await KyberProxy.at('0xf7b8C85953aF2524CcEC98066FCebAF8db27De02');
    instance = await Trader.new(proxy, PLATFORM_FEE);
  });

  describe('#getConversionRates()', () => {

    it('should allow the contract owner to add a trader and increment the totalTraders',
       async () => {

        const conversion = await proxy.getConversionRates(ETH_ADDRESS, KNC_ADDRESS, oneEth, PLATFORM_FEE, '', { from: owner });
        console.log(conversion);
       });
  });
});
```

Running the tests will throw this error: (the object in value being the ABI for IKyberNetwrokProxy.sol)

```
Contract: Trader
       "before each" hook: before test in "Contract: Trader":
     Uncaught RuntimeError: abort(Error: while migrating Trader: invalid address (arg="_kyberProxy", coderType="address", value="[object Object]")). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
```

I think my lack of understanding on proxy addresses and how they are used is causing my struggle but if anyone could shed some light on this I would very much appreciate it.

THanks,
J

Comment: Try `await Trader.new(proxy.address, PLATFORM_FEE);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's examine the error-message that you're getting:

```
"before each" hook: before test in "Contract: Trader":
invalid address (arg="_kyberProxy", coderType="address", value="[object Object]")
```

The 1st line implies that the error occurs inside a `beforeEach` clause.

The 2nd line implies that you are passing an `Object` instead of an `address`.

You don't have a `beforeEach` clause in your code, only a `before` clause, so I take it that you've changed it while trying to solve the problem, and it didn't do the job so you posted a combination of your previous code and the current error or your current code and the previous error.

In either case, examining the `before` clause in your code:

```
proxy = await KyberProxy.at('0xf7b8C85953aF2524CcEC98066FCebAF8db27De02');
instance = await Trader.new(proxy, PLATFORM_FEE);
```

We can see that `proxy` is a `web3.eth.Contract` object (or more precisely, a `TruffleContract` object, which is essentially just a wrapper of the former).

Thus, in `Trader.new(proxy, PLATFORM_FEE)`, you are clearly passing an `Object` instead of an `address`.

You can fix it by replacing `proxy` with `proxy.address`.